# Is there a way to filter some model records unrelated with another model in django admin site?

Tags: django, django-admin

```
class   Town        (models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField  (max_length     = 150,
                                     verbose_name   = _("Human settlement name"),
                                    )
    ref_town    = models.ForeignKey  ('self',
                                     blank          = True,
                                     null           = True,
                                     verbose_name   = _("Superior human settlement"),
                                     help_text      = _("Superior human settlement name (for subordinate settlements)"),
                                    )
class   CoalMine    (models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField  (max_length     = 150,
                                     verbose_name   = _("Coal mine"),
                                     help_text      = _("Coal mine name"))
    town        = models.ForeignKey (Town,
                                     default        = 1,
                                     verbose_name   = _("town"))
```

I have a lot of towns im my data and I need to filter those which are unrelated with coal mines. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since Django 1.3 you can [override SimpleListFilter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) to get it to do what you want.

Comment: I know but I cannot find a way how to filter needed records.